# ProcessMaker Installation Error

Tags: mysql, wamp

Im trying to install ProcessMaker using my WAMP server (Local Machine)
I went through all the steps sucessfully.
But when installing it it fails with a error message saying "Database is not empty" for wf_workflow database and rb_workflow databases

In the installation test page those two fields are with red sign.

Plz help me with this as i am new to this software.

Comment: ServerFault is where you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

That error usually raises when you are trying to install ProcessMaker in a server that has another instance of  it. You have two options and for both on that installation screen you must activate "advanced" settings that will allow you to overwrite existing installation or rename workspace and database names.